# Vim search without overwriting "/ register

Tags: text, vim, latex

> I would like to use a slash (`/`) for a search during a vimscript, but I don't want to overwrite the `"/` register.  How do I do this?

In my particular example, I am working on a custom vim text object for LaTeX, `a$`, to specify the region between and including the previous and next dollar signs (`$` characters, which delimit math mode in LaTeX).  I'm following a guide found [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_new_text_objects) which suggests using a `vnoremap` and an `omap` command, which is a simple enough approach.  What I would like to write is:

```
vnoremap a$ :<C-U> execute "normal! ?\\$\rvN"<CR>
omap a$ :normal va$<CR>
```

However, this implementation has a fatal flaw: the `"/` register becomes overwritten with the search for the dollar sign character, clearing any previous search and causing confusion and inefficiencies when trying to use `n` or `N` next.

Comment: I'm relatively new to vimscript, so I'm welcome to comments and nitpicks on coding style as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `$` are always on the same line then it is often best to use `f` & `t` to make your custom text-objects.

```
xnoremap a$ :<c-u>normal! F$vf$"<cr>
onoremap a$ :normal va$<cr>
```

If your text-object goes over multiple lines then you need to do some kind of searching. Here is an example using `search()` which does not change the search register.

```
xnoremap a$ :<c-u>call search('\$', 'bcW')<cr>m<:call search('\$', 'W')<cr>m>gv
onoremap a$ :normal va$<cr>
```

As @ViVeteran stated you can also use `:keeppatterns` with `/` or `?` to avoid changes to the search register and history.

```
xnoremap :<c-u>execute "keeppatterns normal! ?\\$\<cr>v/\\$"<cr>
onoremap a$ :normal va$<cr>
```

Note: `:keeppatterns` requires Vim 7.4.083+

For more complicated custom text-objects there is [vim-textobj-user](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user/wiki). You may want to look into [vim-textobj-latex](https://github.com/rbonvall/vim-textobj-latex) which use vim-textobject-user to create an assortment of Latex specific text-objects.

For more help see:

```
:h Operator-pending
:h :map-modes
:h c_CTRL-U
:h search()
:h :keeppatterns
```

Answer (score 4):

Save `@/`. Search. Restore `@/`. You might not be able to squeeze all that into a mapping so I'd recommend a function instead:

```
function! VisualAroundDollar()
    let search = @/
    execute "normal! ?\\$\rvN"
    let @/ = search
endfunction

vnoremap a$ :<C-U>call VisualAroundDollar()<CR>
omap a$ :normal va$<CR>
```

Answer (score 4):

May I suggest to consider the command `keeppatterns`

As `:h keeppatterns` says "Execute {command}, without adding anything to the search history" it may help you to build you mapping

Comment: Combining `/` with `keeppattern` seems to only move the cursor to the beginning of a line that contains a matchand will not jump to the start of the match. It also ignores matches on the current line, it seems. As such, `:keepattern /` doesn't really act much like `/`

Answer (score 0):

My [SearchAsQuickJump plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5619) provides an implementation of this. You can use the normal search (`/{pattern}`), but conclude it (in GVIM) via `<S-CR>` instead of `<CR>`. That will search but keep the original search pattern. It also has commands that correspond to the built-in `*` and `#` searches.